# Treasury Bill and Treasury Bond : Quoted Price VS Cash Price VS Value of Bond

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, bond

I have confused by three concepts and following is my understanding:

`Quoted Price` and `Cash price` are totally different things in the `Treasury Bill` and `Treasury Bond`?

In the `Treasury Bill,` they are the two alternative ways to state the amount of coupon over face value 100 and we have the relation
$$\dfrac{n}{360}\times\text{Quoted Price} = 100 - \text{Cash price}.$$

But in the `Treasury Bond,` they describe the current price of bond with the relation:
$$\text{Cash price = Quoted price + Accrued interest since last coupon date}.$$
$$\text{Cash price = Dirty price}$$ 
$$\text{Quoted price = Clean price}$$

The `Value of Bond` is calculated by the zero curve or the yield of the bond, when the coupon structure is known. The `Value of Bond` have the relation with `Quoted Price` and `Cash price` in `Treasury Bond`(>,< or =), but has nothing related in `Treasury Bill.`

I am not sure whether above understanding is correct.

Comment: A treasury bill doesn't have a coupon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bills do not have a coupon.  They are sold at a discount to 100, but you get your 100 back at maturity.  The equation should read 'Quoted Yield' not 'Quoted Price'.  Yield is the effective return on your investment.  The lower the cash price, the higher the return.

The equations for bonds are correct.